# fileupload control wouldn't work in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I'm trying to make a simple uploadfile control with ASP.NET, 
and it wouldnt work:

### Here's my code(.aspx):

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    upload a file now.
      <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload1" runat="server" />
      <asp:Button  ID="button1"  Text="Upload"  runat="server"  Width="73px" 
            onclick="button1_Click" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  Font-Bold="True"  ForeColor="#000099">
         </asp:Label>
  </div>  
</form>
```

### and here's my code behind(.cs):

```
if(fileupload1.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
        if(fileupload1.PostedFile.ContentType ==  "image/jpeg")
        {
            if(fileupload1.PostedFile.ContentLength < 51200000)
            {
               string  filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload1.FileName);
               fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/") + filename);
               Label1.Text ="File uploaded successfully!";
            }
            else
                Label1.Text ="File maximum size is 500 Kb";
        }
        else
            Label1.Text ="Only JPEG files are accepted!";
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        Label1.Text = "The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: "
                           + exc.Message;
    }
  }
```

the file is not presented in the server.. 
any thoughts?

when I breakpoint, they all goes valid, the application gets to the code, it all working , but won't save it to the folders.

Comment: What happens if you put breakpoints on the if statements, are they valid?

Comment: yes, they are all valid, it goes through the code but wouldnt present it in the folders for some reason

Comment: no exceptions at all.

Comment: What does `Server.MapPath("~/img/") + filename` resolve to?

Comment: You need to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` as a form attribute.. otherwise nothing will be uploaded.

Comment: You use the built-in webserver of VS ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That really should be posted as an answer, since it's the most likely cause.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead tried just now, but still no file presented in the folders..

Comment: @thormayer Are you seeing files in the `Request.Files` array when you debug?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead yes Im seeing the file in the dubug .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not work entirely, but you need to include an `enctype` attribute in your form.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If you don't do that, browsers won't transfer the file.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype

Comment: Might be better to reference, say, MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype

Answer (score 1):

change

```
fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/") + filename);
```

with

```
fileupload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/") + filename);
```

Comment: @thormayer if you debug with fiddler do you see the file stream?

Comment: when I debug in VS, I can see the file in the debug.

Comment: @thormayer do you check the folder permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in these two lines

```
string  filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload1.FileName);
fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/") + filename);
```

why are you using

```
 string  filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload1.FileName);
```

It should be simple

```
fileupload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/img/") + fileupload1.FileName);
```