# not able to save file in folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

ASPX:

```
<div> 
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /> <asp:Button ID="submit" Text="submit" runat="server" OnClick="submit_Click" /> 
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into uploaded_data (file_path) values (@file)", con);
        string fileName =Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string filePath = "~/uploads/" + fileName;
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@file", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = filePath ;
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds1);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("upload file");
    }
}
```

`FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));` is not saving file in folder

Comment: Are you getting any error while debugging? Check permission of folder.

Comment: no the code is storing path in db but not saving file in folder

Comment: Is FileUpload1 inside an UpdatePanel?

Comment: no it is not inside updatePanel

Comment: did you checked files inside your applications root/upload folder

Comment: Did you print out with `Response.Write(Server.MapPath(filePath));`? Is that correct path? Are you in debugging mode or running on server?

Comment: whats the file size you uploading?

Comment: `uploads` folder is in root directory?

Comment: yes it is in root directory and the root path is c:\users\sunny\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\fileupload_control\fileupload_control\uploads\1.jpg

Comment: its saving file on disk but not show that folder content  in solution explorer . in sol exp the upload folder is empty but on disk it has stored data

Comment: check this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320743/fileupload-control-wouldnt-work-in-asp-net

Comment: Press "show all Files" option in solution explorer to show the uploaded files.

Comment: have you tried to debug it?? and cehck whether you are getting any file inside `fileuploader1` or not???

Answer (score 1):

Click 'Show All Files' on upper section of Solution Explorer and try 'Refresh' option there.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `string fileName =Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);`

to

`string fileName =Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);`

and make sure this testing

1) Refresh your folder then check

2) Open in your folder then check it

3)

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into uploaded_data (file_path) values (@file)", con);
```

Why you write insert query in `SqlDataAdapter` ? It' is insert query so you need `SqlCommand` and run the query by `ExcuteNonQuery()`

4) Click "show all Files" option in your solution explorer to show the uploaded files. and you need to include that files from if exclude.

5) Clean your solution file and refresh your solution explorer, then check that.

6) This is enough for your problem. It is not a problem

Comment: its saving file on disk but not show that folder content in solution explorer . in sol exp the upload folder is empty but on disk it has stored data –

Comment: Click "show all Files" option in solution explorer to show the uploaded files. and you need to include that files from exclude

Comment: there is not such kind of control in sol exp

Comment: is the `uploads` folder there?

Comment: yes and its saving data to disk and also showing data on disk . but not showing saved date on solution explorer even i restarted my system.

Comment: Clean your solution file and refresh your solution explorer, then check that.

Answer (score 0):

Press "show all Files" option in solution explorer to show the uploaded files.
[image]

Comment: there is no that kindo option

Comment: Check snapshot i uploaded.